# Create a custom LSTM Layer which feedbacks output as input in next time step

Tags: python, lstm, tf.keras, keras-layer

I proceeded with idea of using `raw_rnn` function for writing a custom LSTM Layer, such that output of previous time step is passed as input of next time step. I find it difficult to extend the model with other Layers such as Dense (for example) using functional API, and I'm not sure if the usage of `raw_rnn` allows us to use `model.fit()`?

I proceed with the code below

```py
class CustomLSTMLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):

    def __init__(self, cell, fn, **kwargs):
        super(CustomLSTMLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cell = cell
        self.loop_fn = fn

    def call(self, inputs):
        input_tensor = inputs

        # Apply raw_rnn
        outputs_ta, final_state = tf.compat.v1.nn.raw_rnn(self.cell, loop_fn)

        # Obtain the final outputs tensor
        outputs = outputs_ta.stack()

        return outputs, final_state


def loop_fn(time, cell_output, cell_state, loop_state):

  global batch_size, sequence_length, input_depth

  emit_output = cell_output 
  if cell_output is None: 
    next_cell_state = cell.zero_state(batch_size, tf.float32)
  else:
    next_cell_state = cell_state


  elements_finished = (time >= sequence_length)
  finished = tf.reduce_all(elements_finished)
  next_input = tf.cond(
      finished,
      lambda: None, #tf.zeros([batch_size] +  input_depth, dtype=tf.float32),
      lambda: cell_output)
  
  next_loop_state = None
  return (elements_finished, next_input, next_cell_state,
          emit_output, next_loop_state)
```